# Index of words found in document - Java

Tags: java, indexing, inverted-index

I am trying to write a program that takes in a text file as input, retrieves the words, and outputs each word with each line number that they are located in. I'm having a lot of trouble with this project, although I've made some progress...

So far I have an `ArrayList` which holds all of the words found in the document, without punctuation marks. I am able to output this list and see all the words in the text file, but I do not know where to go from here... any ideas?

example:

```
myList = [A, ACTUALLY, ALMOST,....]
```

I need to somehow be able to associate each word with which line they came from, so I can populate a data structure that will hold each word with their associated line number(s).

I am a programming novice so I am not very familiar with all the types of data structures and algorithms out there... my instructor suggested I use a dynamic multilinked list but I don't know how I would implement that verses ArrayLists and arrays.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A Map seems much better than a linked list

Comment: @Cruncher Although if part of the assignment requires sorting, a `Map` wouldn't work.

Comment: `Collections.sort(map.values());` (not sure if that's exact syntax)

Comment: Where he said about sorting?

Comment: I tell you, sorting a map is a lot easier than sorting a linked list!

Comment: Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> is the way to go. The benefit of using a Map is you can ensure that only one key exists for each word without iterating through the entire list of words you already have. Associated with each key would be an ArrayList of line numbers at which each word was found.

Comment: I'd rather say Map<String, List<Integer>> - coz same word could appear in a number of different lines.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right...edited my answer. 4 PM on a Friday, it's apparently already Miller Time for my noggin :-)

Comment: @ZebbyDee I can hardly keep my eyes open by the time 2:30 rolls around on fridays :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a hash table.  A hash table is a key/value pair.  The key can be every word in the text file, the value, an array list containing the line numbers.

Basically, loop through every word in the text file.  If that word is not in your list of words, add it as the key and the line number as the value in a list into the hash table.  If that word is already in the table, append the line number to the array list.

Java has good docs on a hash table [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

for you to get the methods you need.

Comment: +1 A loop counter to keep track of the line number seems like a good idea too. Be careful though, you need to loop through lines, and then words in the line so that you can keep track of which line you're on.

Comment: Yes, he would have to keep track of that somehow.  Been a while since I have parsed files in Java, but I remember you can read a whole line at a time.  I expect there would be an outer loop to read a line at a time and increment the line number, then an inner loop to iterate over the words in that line.